# mysqli datetime with 3 extra minutes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a saved datatime type on database which is:

> 2014-03-31 18:00:00

now i'm trying to separate the date and time by doing this:

```
$date =  strtotime($row['timedate']);
$formatD = date('F d', $date);
$formatT = date('h:mA', $date);
```

but the output of my **$formatT** has always an extra 3 minutes, which in this case would output **6:03PM**

Is there something i missed?

Thanks.

Comment: `m` is the month, not minutes, and this is March (03) :).

Comment: now i feel so dumb..,haha..,i've been exhausted trying to find my fault..,thank! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` represents the **month**. You need to use `i` for minutes:

```
$formatT = date('h:iA', $date);
```